# How to check which dependency requires hashes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Running pip in `--require-hashes` mode proves to be more and more of a nuisance in a large project that I've been working on, as it forces me to specify exact version of every dependency that I'm using. I haven't specified this requiremenent explicitly and was puzzled by its appearance in my logs; after some digging, I found out that the `--require-hashes` mode is implicitly turned on whenever any dependency install its own requirements with this flag:

```
Hashes are required in --require-hashes mode (implicitly on when a hash is
specified for any package).
```

How can I check whcih dependency requires hashes so that I can try to replace it? Alternatively, is there any other workaround for this that I'm not aware of?

EDIT: I'm using pip `21.3.1`.
My error message is:

> Collecting text-unidecode>=1.3
> ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with ==. These do not:
> text-unidecode>=1.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/a5/c0b6468d3824fe3fde30dbb5e1f687b291608f9473681bbf7dabbf5a87d7/text_unidecode-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=1311f10e8b895935241623731c2ba64f4c455287888b18189350b67134a822e8 (from python-slugify==4.0.1->-r requirements.txt (line 484))

However, it seems like `python-slugify` was a dependency of my project long before this became an issue.

Comment: I don't think dependencies can declare they require hashes. Check your environment variables too. It might be `PIP_REQUIRE_HASHES` or similar.

Comment: What version of pip are you using? My pip always includes a list of affected packages with the error message.

Comment: I'm using pip 21.3.1.

Comment: I check my dockerfile, it seems like nothing to the tune of `PIP_REQUIRE_HASHES` was specified there.

Answer (score 0):

When any of your packages includes a hash in your `requirements.txt`, pip will automatically use the `--require-hashes` flag when installing your dependencies.